# UIImageView can't show a CALayer's contents?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, calayer

After `UILabel` has shown, I can see the `contens` of underling layer is not nil. Then I do that:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:(__bridge CGImageRef)(self.v2.layer.contents)];
UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
iv.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
iv.frame = CGRectMake(100, 200, 120, 120);
[self.window addSubview:iv];
```

But I can't see a image, why? I can see the image view is there, just with a gray backgroud color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when you use `contents` property as a getter, CALayer doesn't return a CGImageRef.
Log the return value and you will see, that you gets a CABackingStore instance (tested in iOS 6.).

```
// label is a UILabel
NSLog(@"%@", self.label.layer.contents);
// NSLog output : <CABackingStore 0x7181b90 (buffer [126 21] BGRA8888)>
```

If you want to transfer the layer contents to an UIImageView, you can assign the original layer contents to the imageView layer contents.

```
UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 120, 120)];
iv.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
iv.layer.contents = self.v2.layer.contents;
[self.window addSubview:iv];
```

Comment: I think you are right, but can I get the backing store image?

Comment: @KarlPeng No, you can't, CABackingStore is a private class.

Comment: @KarlPeng If you want to draw a CALayer into an image context, a little of research on SO will give you answers.